# Why can't home-manager read environment variables using function builtins.getEnv?

Tags: environment-variables, nix, home-manager

Why can't [home-manager](https://nix-community.github.io/home-manager/) read environment variables `$USER` and `$HOME` using Nix function `builtins.getEnv` in `~/.config/home-manager/home.nix`?

```hs
# Excerpt from ~/.config/home-manager/home.nix
...
# Home Manager needs a bit of information about you and the paths it should
# manage.
#home.username = "derek";
home.username = builtins.getEnv "USER";
home.homeDirectory = "/home/derek";
#home.homeDirectory = builtins.getEnv "HOME";
...
```

```bash
alpine-2:~$ home-manager switch

error:
       … while evaluating a branch condition

         at /nix/store/z6w242l49pbrdawkz5vdhfxh2mvsj36c-source/lib/lists.nix:57:9:

           56|       fold' = n:
           57|         if n == len
             |         ^
           58|         then nul

       … while calling the 'length' builtin

         at /nix/store/z6w242l49pbrdawkz5vdhfxh2mvsj36c-source/lib/lists.nix:55:13:

           54|     let
           55|       len = length list;
             |             ^
           56|       fold' = n:

       (stack trace truncated; use '--show-trace' to show the full trace)

       error:
       Failed assertions:
       - Username could not be determined
alpine-2:~$ echo $USER
derek
```

Comment: Quick sanity-check question: Is home-manager invoking nix in impure mode? (`builtins.getEnv` generally doesn't work otherwise).

Comment: Do you mean do I invoke `home-manager --impure switch`?  When I invoke this command, home-manager reports the same error.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, `home-manager switch --impure` did work, though.

Comment: @tobiasBora I added answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77538532/107158.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the command `home-manager switch --impure`, home-manager was able to read environment variables `$USER` and `$HOME`.  `--impure` places home-manager in "impure" mode which allows Nix expressions to contain "impure" function references which don't respect referential transparency (i.e. that may return different results for different input values or environments).